# Java. Создание случайного объекта из списка подклассов родителя

Tags: java, классы, объекты, генерация-случайных-данных

Java 11

**Можно ли как нибудь, не указывая конкретного класса, создать случайный объект из какого то, возможно, списка?**

Возможно вопрос не совсем понятен, но сейчас попробую подробнее его описать.

Предположим, что у меня есть `public class Animal`, а также его наследники - `public class Cat extends Animal`, `public class Dog extends Animal`, `public class Bird extends Animal`.

В некотором методе нужно создать случайный объект класса `Animal`, то есть кошку, собаку или птицу. Но как это сделать? Кроме вот этого способа ничего не приходит на ум:

```
double rand = Math.random();
if (rand < 0.33) {
    new Dog();
} else if (rand < 0.66) {
    new Cat();
} else {
    new Bird();
}
```

Есть ли альтернатива этому способу? То есть, возможно ли указать список подклассов класса `Animal`, а потом создать случайно выбранный объект из этого списка? Если да, то как это сделать?

Пробовал сделать это через интерфейсы, сделать `implements` для каждого подкласса, а потом получить все подклассы этого интерфейса: `UnknownInterface.class.getClasses()`, но он возвращал пустой массив.

Comment: Только с помощью рефлексии, но её стоит избегать.

Comment: То есть самый лучший и единственный способ - на подобии того примера, что я дал в вопросе?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev

Comment: в данном случае я за рефлексию. разумеется, с помощью рефлексии можно легко отстрелить себе ногу (и, скорее всего, у вас именно так и получится), но с другой стороны рефлексия - очень мощный механизм, без ее помощи не обходится ни в одном фреймворке. посему понимать ее надо, а другого способа нет. так что удачи вам в отстреливании своей ноги, а, если повезет, то и двух

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определим классы животных

```
class Animal {
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat() {
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog() {
    }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
    public Bird() {
    }
}
```

Потом интерфейс фабрики

```
interface AnimalFactory {
    Animal create();
}
```

Накидаем фабрик

```
class CatFactory implements AnimalFactory {
    @Override
    public Animal create() {
        return new Cat();
    }
}

class DogFactory implements AnimalFactory {
    @Override
    public Animal create() {
        return new Dog();
    }
}

class BirdFactory implements AnimalFactory {
    @Override
    public Animal create() {
        return new Bird();
    }
}
```

В том числе рандомную

```
class RandomFactory implements AnimalFactory {
    AnimalFactory[] factories;
    Random r = new Random();

    public RandomFactory(AnimalFactory[] factories) {
        this.factories = factories;
    }

    @Override
    public Animal create() {
        int ind = r.nextInt(factories.length);
        return factories[ind].create();
    }
}
```

Ну и запустим это все

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomFactory factory = new RandomFactory(new AnimalFactory[]{
            new CatFactory(),
            new DogFactory(),
            new BirdFactory()
    });

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        Animal animal = factory.create();
        System.out.println(animal.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Вывод

```
com.company.Bird
com.company.Bird
com.company.Cat
com.company.Cat
com.company.Cat
com.company.Dog
com.company.Cat
com.company.Bird
com.company.Cat
com.company.Dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь рефлексией.

```
class Animal {

}

class Cat extends Animal{
    public Cat(){}
} 
class Dog extends Animal{
    public Dog(){}
} 
class Bird extends Animal{
    public Bird(){}
}


class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Class<? extends Animal>[] classes = new Class[]{
            Cat.class,
            Dog.class,
            Bird.class
        };

        Random r = new Random();
        int ind = r.nextInt(3);
        Constructor<? extends Animal> constructor = classes[ind].getConstructor();
        Object[] arguments = new Object[]{};
        Animal animal = (Animal) constructor.newInstance(arguments);
        System.out.println(animal);

    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/g1XvGD

Метод [getConstructor()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) принимает произвольное количество объектов `Class<?>`, которые соответствуют типам аргументов конструктора. Напрмиер:

```
classes[ind].getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
```

Сами аргементы нужно добавить в массив `arguments` соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с Java 8 можно так:

```
ArrayList<Supplier<? extends Animal>> knownAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
knownAnimals.add(Dog::new);
knownAnimals.add(Cat::new);

int randomIndex = ...
Animal animal = knownAnimals.get(randomIndex).get();
```

Рефлексия не требуется.